# Setting number of copies when printing from swift

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swift3

I have setup a pdf etc. to print from my MacOS application, but I cannot figure out how to set the number of print copies in swift, everything else is there but I can't find the number of copies.

Comment: Thanks Eric, ill try and do some research into that question.

Comment: If I remember well (not sure) it should be in NSPrintInfo or in the related properties like jobs pool.